# Django DateField returns DateTime object in test

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-testing

I use Django 1.7b2 and Django REST framework and write some test cases.

There is a custom User model which `birthday` field is added as below.

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True)
    ...
    ...

    gender = models.IntegerField(choices=Gender.CHOICES, default=Gender.UNKNOWN)
    birthday = models.DateField(default=timezone.datetime.today())
```

Then I create TestAPI.

```
class ApiTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        user, created = User.objects.get_or_create(
            username="username",
            email="uname@app.com",
            first_name="fname",
            last_name="lname",
        )    
        self.factory = APIRequestFactory()
        self.client = APIClient()



def test_user_put(self):
    print self.user.birthday
    data = {
            "first_name": self.user.first_name,
            "last_name": self.user.last_name,
            "email": self.user.email,
            "gender": self.user.gender,
            "birthday": self.user.birthday,
    }
    response = self.client.put(reverse('user-detail', args=[self.user.pk]), data)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

The problem is here, when I run this test with **empty database** it raises error that `birthday is not in valid` because test function prints `datetime object` instead of `date object`.

However, after I add a couple of users to database it passes the test.

I repeated this 3-4 times with different definitions (used datetime instead of timezone etc.) but cannot resolve the problem.

Is this something that I miss or a potential bug in framework?

Comment: Are you sure about your setup code? The parenthesis seems off, and you don't assign `self.user` anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

From [the django docs regarding DateField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#datefield):

**DateField.auto_now_add**

Automatically set the field to now when the object is first created. Useful for creation of timestamps. Note that the current date is always used; it’s not just a default value that you can override.

So try writing your code like this:

```
birthday = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True).
```